# How do you solve this $\int\limits ^{\infty }_{0}\frac{\cos( x)}{x^{n} +1} dx,\ n >0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Me and my friend have tried a wedge,a triangle, and we even tried Feynman's technique. None of these things got us an answer to the integral $\int\limits ^{\infty }_{0}\frac{\cos( x)}{x^{n} +1} dx,\ n >0$

Can someone show the process of solving this?

Comment: laplace transform, fourier transform, blablabla. It looks like theres a nice answer for $n=2$ but idk about other $n$

Comment: And [residue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594007/complex-integral-with-residuals/2595093#2595093) (part 2)?

Comment: For $n=2$ you get $\frac{\pi }{e}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first note is that if **$n$ is an odd number** then there is no simple expression for this integral. So lets suppose *n to be an even number*.

That is $n=2m ;m=1,2,3,...$

Let's look at a more general integral

$$I(2m)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^{2m}+b^{2m}}dx$$

where $a,b$ are positive, real numbers.

This integral is equivalent to the following integral:
$$I(2m)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iax}}{x^{2m}+b^{2m}}dx$$

(taking into account $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$)

The simplest way to compute this integral is to use the contour integration method.

Lets take the simplest contour,$C$, that means a semicircle, in the upper half plane, with radius $R\rightarrow \infty$ and consider along the contour the following complex integral

$$I(2m)=\frac{1}{2}\int_C\frac{e^{iaz}}{z^{2m}+b^{2m}}dz$$

Along the real axis we get the desired integral but along the circular half-arc the integral vanishes.

So we can apply Cauchy's Theorem of Residues

Isolated singularities of the integrand $$f(z)=\frac{e^{iaz}}{z^{2m}+b^{2m}}$$ we find by solving the equation

$$z^{2m}+b^{2m}=0$$

Solutions:

$$z_k=be^{i\frac{2k+1}{2m}\pi};k=0,1,2,...,2m-1$$

Only the first $m$ of them ($z_0,z_1,...z_{m-1}$) are located inside the countour.

The end result:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^{2m}+b^{2m}}dx=\frac{i\pi}{2m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{e^{iaz_k}}{z_k^{2m-1}}$$

So computing this integral boils down to the complex algebra.

An example:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^6+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{6e}\left [1+\sqrt e (\cos\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} +\sqrt 3\sin\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}) \right ]$$

Comment: Wow! thank you for your awesome answer!